# Continuous rotation

Tags: objective-c, rotation, uiimage, nstimer

I have a few lines of code that change the image of a button and then rotate it. How do I have the image continue to rotate as the timer continues to increase. Also, how do I stop the rotation and change the image back when the `NSTimer` is reset? Here is some code:

```
-(void)tick{
    timeTick++;
    NSString *timeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", timeTick];
    labelTime.text = timeString;

    UIImage* timebuttonImg =[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
    [timebutton setImage:timebuttonImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    timebutton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(4);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

1. If you don't need to use a timer, consider just using animation. To start rotation:

   ```
   CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
   rotationAnimation.fromValue = @(0.0);
   rotationAnimation.toValue = @(M_PI * 2.0);
   rotationAnimation.duration = 1.0;
   rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
   rotationAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;

   [self.button.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
   ```

   And to stop animation:

   ```
   [self.button.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
   ```

   And after stopping the animation, if you want to animate it back to the original position:

   ```
   CALayer *currentLayer = (CALayer *)[self.button.layer presentationLayer];
   CGFloat  currentAngle = [(NSNumber *)[currentLayer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];

   self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(currentAngle);

   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
       self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
   }];
   ```
2. If you really want to use a `NSTimer`, you could do something like the following to start the timer:

   ```
   self.angle = 0.0;
   NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(tick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
   self.timer = timer;
   ```

   This obviously assumes you have properties for the `angle` and the `timer`:

   ```
   @property (weak, nonatomic) NSTimer  *timer;
   @property (nonatomic)       CGFloat   angle;
   ```

   And the `tick:` routine could do something like:

   ```
   - (void)tick:(NSTimer *)timer
   {
       // update label if you want

       self.angle += 0.1; // increment it by whatever you want (measured in radians)
       if (self.angle > (M_PI * 2.0))
           self.angle = fmodf(self.angle, M_PI * 2.0);

       self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(self.angle);
   }
   ```

   And to stop the timer:

   ```
   [self.timer invalidate];
   self.timer = nil;
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
       self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
   }];
   ```

   And don't forget to call that stop timer code when the view is dismissed (e.g. in `viewDidDisappear`), because if the timer is still going when the view is dismissed, it will maintain a strong reference to the view controller.
3. Perhaps better, to assure constant rotation speed despite the frequency of the `NSTimer` calls (because you're not absolutely assured the frequency of these `NSTimer` calls) is to use the time elapsed to figure out the rotation. So, define properties for the `timer` and the `startTime`:

   ```
   @property (weak, nonatomic) NSTimer       *timer;
   @property (nonatomic)       CFAbsoluteTime startTime;
   ```

   To start the `timer` and set the `startTime`:

   ```
   self.startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
   NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/60.0 target:self selector:@selector(tick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
   self.timer = timer;
   ```

   And then `tick:`

   ```
   - (void)tick:(NSTimer *)timer
   {
       CGFloat elapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - self.startTime;
       CGFloat angle = fmodf(elapsed * kRotationsPerSecond, 1.0) * M_PI * 2.0;

       self.button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
   }
   ```

   And the stop timer code is like above.

   But the idea is that if the rotation speed is critical (e.g. you're doing a sweeping second hand), refer the the device's clock to calculate the degree of rotation.

Answer (score 0):

timebutton.transform is the right direction.

The transform property transforms it relative to its original positioning (before any transformations). To continuously rotate it, you need something like:

`timebutton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(timeTick * 2*M_PI/<TicksPerCircle>); // 2*M_PI is a circle`

To reset it, do:

`timebutton.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;` // edit from Rob's answer

The rotation of 0 says "use original transform matrix".

NOTE:

It rotates around to its anchor point (a property you can set). Anchor points are a 0.0-1.0 scale where 1.0 is the view's layer's height/width.

EX: anchor point (1.0, 0.0) is centered around the top right of the view's layer.

EDIT:

NumTotalTicks -> TicksPerCircle // clearer naming

Comment: What do I put in for <NumTotalTicks>?

Comment: However many ticks you need to have in a circle. If you have a clock, and you're rotating an hours hand, you need 12 as your <numTotalTicks>.

Comment: Got it. I also want the image to rotate around the center of it. The pivot point is currently set to something weird. How would I change it to the center of the image?

Comment: Set the anchor point to (0.5, 0.5). I believe the code is something like: `[[timebutton layer] setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)];`

Comment: Even with your code, the image still moves around. To clarify, I would like the image to rotate without changing position. Thoughts?

Comment: You image is probably not centered then. You may have white space on the sides/top/bottom

Comment: I don't believe this is why. My image is a transparent circle. How can I fix this?

Comment: Verify that there's no extra space on the whole button (not just the image). The image is a part of the button and is layed out inside of the button. Buttons center their image on the left side, so be careful of the button dimensions.

Other than that, play around with different anchor points.